# Adding a border to ffmpeg video [ffmpeg-python]

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making a xmas card and I need to embed the video inside a card on the right (inside the border) and have some text displayed on the left.

For simplicity, let's assume I have a box with a hole which is transparent. I would like to display the video inside that hole.

I am using `ffmpeg-python` and it would be great to see examples of how it can be achieved. It's also fine to post a native ffmpeg solution, although there are some example of that I believe already.

From what I understand, I need to always start with a master node e.g. the biggest node, and place the video inside the hole.

However, when I try something like:

```
import ffmpeg

in_file = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')
border_box = ffmpeg.input('box.png')


(
    ffmpeg.overlay(
        border_box, in_file, x=50, y=50
    )
    .output('out.mp4')
    .run()
)
```

It doesn't work. But vice versa, e.g. putting a border box inside the video doesn't work as it overlays borders of the video.

## What I think needs to be done

1. Create an infinite video from a static `box.png`
2. Overlay, while scaling both streams appropriately
3. Create output

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

The reason for transparency is because it's not actually a rectangle. I could place a video inside a heart shape etc.

Comment: Is `box.png` a solid color, or does it show an image, or art, etc?

Comment: It's a frame, which has a design, so it's an image. I think I can also pad the video, and then overlay the image. It seems like the correct way to go?

Comment: This would be easiest to answer if you provide a mockup image showing the result you want.

Comment: I've made the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work.

Build sample input `box.png` and `video.mp4` using `FFmpeg` in command line:

Build 5 seconds video in resolution 160x120:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=rate=10:size=160x120 -t 5 -c:v libx264 video.mp4
```

Last frame of `video.mp4` (resolution 160x128):
[image]

Build single png image in resolution 260x220:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=260x220 -frames:v 1 box.png
```

`box.png` (resolution 260x228):
[image]

Executing your code in Python:

```
import os
import ffmpeg

in_file = ffmpeg.input('video.mp4')
border_box = ffmpeg.input('box.png')

(
    ffmpeg.overlay(
        border_box, in_file, x=50, y=50
    )
    .output('out.mp4')
    .run()
)
```

Last frame of `out.mp4` (resolution 260x220):
[image]

I executed the test using the latest version of `ffmpeg` (4.2) and `ffmpeg-python` (0.2.0) packages.